# Memory allocation error OpenCV cvReleaseMat

Tags: c, opencv

```
CvMat* traindata=cvCreateMat(1000,36,CV_32FC1);
```

When I try to release this matrix using `cvReleaseMat(&trainData)`

I find memory in the task manager  not decreased...instead this release command doesn't have any effect on memory of this application in task manager.

what my doubt is...does `cvReleaseMat`  frees the memory in the CPU also? Or does it just makes that matrix invisble in the future?

Comment: I don't know if you know valgrind http://valgrind.org/. It's designed to answer these kind of questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `cvReleaseMat` does free the memory. The task-manager isn't really the tool to look at the memory of the CvMat* allocation. Although if you would make the matrix much larger, you might notice it. This Matrix occupies 1000 * 36 * 4 = 144000 bytes.

You can see it back in the output of the following code analysed by valgrind:

```
CvMat* traindata = cvCreateMat(1000, 36, CV_32FC1);
//cvReleaseMat(&traindata);
```

the relevant valgrind output is:

```
==4967== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4967==     in use at exit: 144,108 bytes in 2 blocks
==4967==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 8 frees, 144,772 bytes allocated
==4967== 
==4967== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4967==    definitely lost: 64 bytes in 1 blocks
==4967==    indirectly lost: 144,044 bytes in 1 blocks
==4967==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4967==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4967==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

but if you actually release the `CvMat`

```
CvMat* traindata = cvCreateMat(1000, 36, CV_32FC1);
cvReleaseMat(&traindata);
```

you get this output notice the output of valgrind now:

```
==4957== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4957==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4957==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 144,772 bytes allocated
==4957== 
==4957== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: i dont know about this valgrind ..but i'm sure this would help me out..can you provide link to any demo examples of using valgrind with OpenCV in Windows

Comment: I posted the link to their website under your original question as comment, you might accept this answer if you think it's good.

Comment: @user2527599 about your valgrind question see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows